# assertj + how to identify which property is failing when using tuple

Tags: assertj

I am using assertj's tuple to combine two or three property together and check the combination. Now I am having the issue of identifying out of which property it is failing.

Currently am using the as below:

```
softAssertions.assertThat(resultArrayList)
                              .extracting("title", "address.countryName", "address.state", "address.city")
                              .as("Title, CountryName, State, City at position %s", i)
                              .containsAnyOf(
                                      new Tuple(placeToSearch, expectedCountry, expectedState, expectedCity));
```

and I get a failure message as

```
[Title, CountryName, State, City at position 0]        
Expecting
      <[("DOT Baires Shopping", "Argentina", "Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires", "Ciudad de Buenos Aires")]>
    to contain at least one of the following elements:
      <[("Dot", "Argentina", "Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires", "Ciudad de Buenos Aires")]>
```

1) Some suggestion to identify/mark the failed data. 2) Any way to colour the failed ones

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have a list of one tuple, this tuple does not match the expected tuple as their first value differ (`"Dot"` vs `"DOT Baires Shopping"`). Tuple `equals` method compares all tuple values.

It should be possible to color the actual and expected list but not specific elements (it's an IDE thing, not really an AssertJ thing).

A few remarks:

- using `containsAnyOf(expected)` with one element is the same as using `contains(expected)`
- `Assertions` expose a `tuple(...)` factory method to avoid calling `new Tuple(...)`

Hope it helps

Comment: yes, in above example first value differs and I want to find out if there is way to change the message to indicate that, as in current message style not clear which one has changed.